# Return array type from stack or table - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem with my code. Maybe simple, maybe not - for first lets look at this.

```js
var tab = [];

do{
    var i = 0;
    tab.push(prompt("Write some type of array!"));
    i++;
    
}while(confirm("Next array?"));

for (var i=0; i<tab.length; i++)
    document.write(typeof(tab[i])+"<br>");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="author" content="Donio3d">
    
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    
        
    
    </BODY>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
</HTML>
```

So i want to return a type of array from stack. Everything is always a string.

Is there any way to do this, without checking by IF statement?

Comment: `type of array` I don't understand what you mean by this, and the result is correct, what you enter from the prompt will be a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `typeof` of the input you have to first checking if it is a number using [Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) and for simplicity also used [Unary plus (+) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).

Code:

```js
const tab = [];
const getInputTyeof  = i => typeof (!Number.isNaN(+i) ? +i : i);

do {
  tab.push(prompt('Write some type of array!'));
} while (confirm('Next array?'));

tab.forEach(input => document.write(getInputTyeof(input) + '<br>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`prompt` will always return you a `string` type so you need to make a custom logic with `isNaN()` to separate out the string and integer values. Something like this below:

```js
var tab = [];

do{
    var i = 0;
    tab.push(prompt("Write some type of array!"));
    i++;
    
}while(confirm("Next array?"));

var integerType = [];
var stringType = [];
for (var i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
  if(isNaN(tab[i])){
    stringType.push(tab[i]);
  } else {
    integerType.push(tab[i]);
  }

}
console.log('Integer type array ' + integerType);
console.log('String type array ' + stringType);
```

Comment: Hey, you probably did not understood my question.

I want to return a integer, when it will be "123", and string when a text. Not always string.

I want to collect arrays into a stack, and then print wchich one is a number type, and wchich is a text.

Comment: @Donio3d `prompt` will always return you a `string` type

Comment: So what can i do to return different types, not always string?

Comment: @Donio3d check my updated answer. That should help you now.

Answer (score 0):

Since promt will always return a string in your example you have to figure out if the input may represent a other type or not, using something like this:

```js
var tab = [];

do{
    var i = 0;
    tab.push(parseType(prompt("Write some type of array!")));
    i++;
    
}while(confirm("Next array?"));

for (var i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
  document.write((typeof tab[i])+"<br>");
}


function parseType(e){
  if(parseFloat(e) == e && Number.isFinite(parseFloat(e))){
    return parseFloat(e);
  }
  return e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tab = [];

do{
    var i = 0;
    tab.push(parseType(prompt("Write some type of array!")));
    i++;
    
}while(confirm("Next array?"));

for (var i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
  document.write((typeof tab[i])+"<br>");
}


function parseType(e){
  if(parseFloat(e) == e && Number.isFinite(parseFloat(e))){
    return parseFloat(e);
  }
  return e;
}
```

Hey! That is exacly what i was looking for. Thanks for help!